# use express.js to get the query string of a url

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm looking for a way to get the query string part of a url using node.js or one of it's extension module. 
I've tried using url and express but they give me an array of parameters. 
I want to original string. 
Any ideas ?

example; for:

> http://www.mydom.com?a=337&b=33

give me

> a=337&b=33

(with or without the ?)

Comment: Not sure but are u looking for req.query.a || req.query.b ??

Comment: just the query part (all the string, not just the params. url.parse gives and object that the .search property gives the answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`url.parse`](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost). By default it will return an object whose `query` property is the query string. (You can pass `true` as the second argument if you want `query` to be an object instead, but since you want a string the default is what you want.)

```
var url = require('url');

var urlToParse = 'http://www.mydom.com/?a=337&b=33';
var urlObj = url.parse(urlToParse);

console.log(urlObj.query);
// => a=337&b=33
```

Comment: [`req.originalUrl`](http://expressjs.com/4x/api.html#req.originalUrl) can be the `urlToParse`. (Or, [`req.url`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_message_url) when you aren't using Express.)

Comment: actually it was urlObj.search that gave me the solution. both you and @Touffy are correct using the parse tool. the .query gives me an array of params. for the string I  used .search.

Answer (score 1):

How about using the built-in [url.parse](https://nodejs.org/api/url.html#url_url_parse_urlstr_parsequerystring_slashesdenotehost) method?